# why does the milling machine require FR4 material

Tags: pcb-fabrication

At a hackspace I frequently attend, there is a milling machine called the Roland Modela MDX-20 Desktop Miller. We use this milling machine to make pcbs however the technician there stresses we must use FR4 material on the miller why? What so special about FR4?

Comment: Could it be that the technician provided certain drill bits that shouldn't be used on other materials that would break the bit otherwise?

Comment: Teflon pcb material causes, so I've been told, much more wear on a milling cutter. "FR4 only" is a much more clear rule than having to figure out the properties of each material a user might bring in to the shop.

Comment: Asking your technician could provide you with insight you're looking for.  After all, he's the one behind this regulation.  Ask politely: "I'll certainly use FR4 as required, but I'm curious..."  I think, only somebody who have milled boards on a similar machine and explored different materials can answer your question properly (or debunk the regulation).
Oh, if you find out from your technician, don't forget to post it here.

Answer (score 2):

All milling machines have a range of materials that can be used.  You probably wouldn't expect this machine to mill steel, and you certainly wouldn't expect it to mill diamond!

FR4 is a glass-reinforced epoxy resin; it has certain mechanical properties for which the mill is designed.  FR4 is by far the most common PCB material, so this is a reasonable design decision for this special-purpose mill.

It's probably capable of milling similar materials, but it's sensible to limit this without further consultation.  You should be wary of milling other PCB materials that aren't designed to be similar to FR4, many employ ceramics which will be hard on the bits or plastics like Teflon which will melt.  Alternatively, you might be interested in building aluminum PCBs for thermal applications, but I've never heard of milling these and it would probably be *extremely* easy to short traces out to the substrate.

Answer (score 2):

At first sight this is a strange recommendation, as FR4 wears out tools quickly. However, older PCB materials like Pertinax (FR2) are more fragile, and I guess the bit will splinter them.

Or he may mean not to use the mill for other materials than PCBs. Steel or aluminium for instance require a different milling speed.

Like Nick says, ask the man. If he tells you not to use the machine on anything but FR4, at least he himself should know why. Report back here when you find out.